# Have mule call http process that expects multipart/form-data

Tags: mule

I have a backend process that expects multipart/form-data. I'd like to have mule call it and return the results. Here is a simple flow that I've worked up. However, the outbound-endpoint doesn't transform the message into multipart/form-data. The backend process just gets the body that was initially posted in.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<flow name="testFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" mimeType="text/plain" contentType="text/plain" />
    <message-properties-transformer>
        <add-message-property key="f" value="#[payload:java.lang.String]"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="x12backend" port="9877" path="dummy.php" contentType="multipart/form-data"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only messages with attachments are automatically turned into multipart request entities so the best for you would be to:

- Move the message payload to an outbound attachment: the attachment name will be used for the part name. Use the `set-attachment` and `set-payload` message processors or a Groovy transformer for that.
- Set the message payload to org.mule.transport.NullPayload (with `set-payload` and a `#[null]` expression, otherwise it'll be posted a second time in a part named "payload".

Comment: thanks, any ideas if Mule ESB will have a more standard way to do this?

Comment: yes, I reviewed my answer to suggest using standard message processors instead of Groovy.